# How to select prepended element

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, upload

i have a upload form that uses the new multiple attribute and i made an ajax upload form to make things more user friendly. My problem is im trying to update percentages for all of these files that are being uploaded and appended to a div, instead of one percentage being updated all of them get updated from the last file. Here is some code.

```
$('#File').change(function(event) {
        for(I = 0; I < this.files.length; I++)
        {
            var Name = this.files[I].name;
            var Size = this.files[I].size;
            var Type = this.files[I].type;

            $('#UploadContent').prepend('<div class="UploadLabel" style="width:60%;">'+Name+'</div><div class="UploadLabel UploadPercent" style="width:10%;">0%</div><div class="UploadLabel" style="width:15%;">N/A</div><div class="UploadLabel" style="width:15%;">'+Type+'</div>');
            var Data = new FormData();
            Data.append('File[]', this.files[I]);
            var Request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            Request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event){
                if(event.lengthComputable)
                {
                    var Percent = event.loaded / event.total;
                    var Progress = $('#UploadContent').find('.UploadPercent');
                    $(Progress).text(Math.round(Percent * 100) + '%');
                }
            });
            Request.upload.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
        });

            Request.open('POST', '/Home/Upload/Upload.php');
            Request.setRequestHeader('Chache-Control', 'no-cache');
            Request.send(Data);
            $('#UploadModal').fadeIn('fast');
        }
    });
```

now as you can see in the progress listener my

```
var progress = $('#UploadContent').find('.UploadPercent');
```

how would i select the file that is supposed to be updated correctly. If someone can find a comepletely different method to change the percent that would be great too! - Thanks!

Comment: As I understood you want to select prepended element? if so, you ought first create it with jquery var someElement = $("what element you want") and then prepend it

Comment: good idea! let me try that.

Comment: could you write an answer i couldnt get it to work @GiviKesanashvili

Comment: Here is Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/87SwD/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're prepending, add a new, specific `class` (yes, you could use an `id`, but I'd just stick to `class`) to the `.UploadPercent` element:

```
$('#UploadContent').prepend('<div class="UploadLabel" style="width:60%;">'+Name+'</div><div class="UploadLabel UploadPercent UploadTarget' + I + '" style="width:10%;">0%</div><div class="UploadLabel" style="width:15%;">N/A</div><div class="UploadLabel" style="width:15%;">'+Type+'</div>');
// LOOK HERE----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^ HERE
```

And when you're targeting, use this:

```
var progress = $('#UploadContent').find('.UploadTarget' + I);
```

Because you need the value of `I` to be accurate based on where you are in the loop, you need to use a closure as well. So your code will end up looking like:

```
$('#File').change(function(event) {
    for(I = 0; I < this.files.length; I++) {
        (function (I) {
            // Your current code inside the for loop
        })(I);
    }
});
```

While the example from above is definitely an option, it probably makes more sent to just store a reference to the newly inserted element and not have to deal with a new `class` and `I`, and then use it later.

Here is the final code I'd use:

http://jsfiddle.net/MeL7L/2/

```
$("#File").on("change", function (event) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
        (function (curFile, i) {
            var Name = curFile.files[i].name;
            var Size = curFile.files[i].size;
            var Type = curFile.files[i].type;

            var newEl = "";
            newEl += '<div class="UploadLabel" style="width:60%;">' + Name + '</div>';
            newEl += '<div class="UploadLabel UploadPercent" style="width:10%;">0%</div>';
            newEl += '<div class="UploadLabel" style="width:15%;">N/A</div>';
            newEl += '<div class="UploadLabel" style="width:15%;">' + Type + '</div>';
            newEl = $(newEl);
            $("#UploadContent").prepend(newEl);
            var Data = new FormData();
            Data.append("File[]", curFile.files[i]);
            var Request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            Request.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (event){
                if (event.lengthComputable) {
                    var Percent = event.loaded / event.total;
                    var Progress = newEl.find(".UploadPercent");
                    Progress.text(Math.round(Percent * 100) + "%");
                }
            });
            Request.upload.addEventListener("load", function(event) {});

            Request.open("POST", "/Home/Upload/Upload.php");
            Request.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            Request.send(Data);
            $("#UploadModal").fadeIn("fast");
        })(this, i);
    }
});
```

Comment: @MoussaHarajli Sorry, I misunderstood the real problem. I just updated my answer. I added an extra class to the `.UploadPercent` element - `".UploadTarget" + I`. That way you can find the specific element

Comment: its not working because I isnt a global you are trying to add I in the function.

Comment: @MoussaHarajli I'm not sure what you all mean. I just updated my answer again with a final version of your full code that I'd use. Try that out. If it doesn't work, explain what isn't working.

Comment: now nothing works with that! if you want to try it out yourself head to http://67.184.73.19

Comment: @MoussaHarajli Sorry about that. I messed up a little thing because of your use of `this`. I updated my answer again with the code I'd use. Try that and let me know how it goes.

Comment: @MoussaHarajli Sorry again. There was a typo for the `class`. I made one minor edit to my answer. Try my code once more and let me know. Hopefully this is works now.

Comment: @MoussaHarajli Cool, that's great! Sorry for all the confusion and typos and mess-ups. Glad you got it working now :)